# Jquery verification bypass

Tags: jquery

all

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function insertAuthKey() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/misc.php?action=getAuthKey',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(res) {
                jQuery('input[name=authKey]').val(res.key);
            }
        });
    }
    insertAuthKey();
    jQuery('button[class=newAuthKey]').on('click', function() {
        jQuery.get('/misc.php?action=newAuthKey', function(res) {
            insertAuthKey();
        })
    });
});
```

ihave this code right here of a website which checks for rank of member in a forum if it's vip it will give a key can i get something into console to give always a key ? like now the input tell me : Vip is needed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I also reported the question, the downvotes keep coming lol. Is there a downvote limit at SO?

Comment: I've seen to -8 but it is not the down voting only it needs 5 closing votes

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is not a hackers community to help you hack websites.

Besides that the code you posted is useless since it only shows an ajax post and get to php files, the actual key generation is inside the php code which you obviously can't access.